Is there any nonlinear function $f(x)$ whose derivative is 0 somewhere and for which both $\sin (f(x))$ and $\cos(f(x))$ have closed form integrals?
The question arises from this simpler one:
Is there any nonlinear function $f(x)$ for which both $\sin (f(x))$ and $\cos(f(x))$ have closed form integrals?

Have you considered $f(x)=\arcsin g(x)$ and other inverse trigonometric functions?

Yes, take $f(x)=\arcsin(\cos(x)^2)$. You can show that this function has a derivative of $0$ at $x=\pi/2$. Moreover, $\sin(f(x))=\cos(x)^2$, which clearly has a closed form integral, and we can also show $\cos(f(x))$ has a closed-form integral by asking Wolfram Alpha.
$$
\int \cos(\arcsin(\cos(x)^2))dx=\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^4(x)}\left(\sqrt{\cos(2x)+3}\cot(x)+\sqrt{2}\csc(x)\log\left(\sqrt{2}\cos(x)+\sqrt{\cos(2x)+3}\right)\right)}{2\sqrt{\cos(2x)+3}}+C
$$
